# Struts empty ActionForm

Tags: jsp, struts1, actionform

I'm a Struts newbie, and using Struts 1.2.7. My goals is to be able to read the form in my action class that helped built my JSP.  I am able to use the form in my JSP/Struts to create a data table and I can clear the data from the table, all through the action class execute method.  However, what I can not do is read/view the same form that created the JSP in my action class execute method.  What I get is an empty ActionForm passed to my action class execute method.  My first guess is I have an JSP/HTML problem.  I assume this is a very basic question and any help would be welcomed.

```
<html:form action="/PolicyServiceTaskAssignment" >
.....
            <!-- Update and Clear submit table -->
            <table align="center" style="width: 450px;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                        <html:submit property="update" value="Update" style="height: 25px"
                            styleId="Update" styleClass="buttonMouseOut"
                            onmouseover="onButtonMouseOver(this.id);"
                            onmouseout="onButtonMouseOut(this.id);" />
                        <html:submit property="clear" value="Clear" style="height: 25px"
                            styleId="Clear" styleClass="buttonMouseOut"
                            onmouseover="onButtonMouseOver(this.id);"
                            onmouseout="onButtonMouseOut(this.id);" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Display user's tasks table -->
            <table id="entryTable">
                <logic:notEmpty name="PolicyServiceTaskAssignmentForm"
                    property="tasksList">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            Job Name
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            Experience Level
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            Task Name
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            Completion Time
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <logic:iterate id="row" name="PolicyServiceTaskAssignmentForm" property="tasksList" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <html:checkbox styleClass="checkbox" name="row" property="checked" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <bean:write name="row" property="jobName" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <bean:write name="row" property="experienceLevel" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <bean:write name="row" property="taskName" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <bean:write name="row" property="completionTime" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </logic:iterate>

....
</table>
</html:form>
```

Comment: in your strings mapping xml file check what form is specified and type cast this empty form to that. If this works you should get all the fields inside it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want me to go into the struts.xml and check the type mapping.  I believe I have done that, see below.

Comment: <action
      attribute="PolicyServiceTaskAssignmentForm"
      input="/PolicyServiceTaskAssignment.jsp"
      name="PolicyServiceTaskAssignmentForm"
      path="/PolicyServiceTaskAssignment"
      scope="request"
      parameter="method"
      type="com.llic.web.action.PolicyServiceTaskAssignmentAction"
      validate="false">
      <forward name="load"  path="/PolicyServiceTaskAssignment.jsp" />
      <forward name="exception" path="/exception.jsp" />
      <forward name="failure" path="/PolicyServiceTaskAssignment.jsp" />
    </action>

Comment: As per your above comment, your form is PolicyServiceTaskAssignmentForm, typecast your form inside action class to this form.

Comment: So, when I removed the "scope="request"" from the struts.xml action tag, I was able to see my fully populated form returned to my action class.  Thanks Amitmah for your help.

Comment: For future reference, instead of wedging code/config into illegible comments, edit the question to include all relevant information. Also, did you even notice that the original code you *did* post wasn't even visible?!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.